# Neural Network - Vector Centric Python implementation

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation

Hello I try to use a vector-centric Neural Network with one input node, one output node and two hidden layer with 3 nodes each to fit a very easy x**2 function. - Just to verify its functionality. Therefore I use the code below. As result I get the orange line, the blue line is the true line.

[image]

As you can see something is not working. I have tried to change the number of iterations together with the value of the learning rate but no success. If I plot the Loss over the iterations, I get the following picture for 100 Iterations:

[image]

I have not added bias yet but I think this easy function should be fit-able without extra bias nodes. Additionally I assume the failure in the code most likely to be in the "Calculate the Gradients with respect to the weights" part of the code...

So in principal I have two questions:

1. Is there any basic failure in my code such that the code CAN not work
2. If not, why does my model fail to fit the easy data

Thanks for help in advance!

Here comes the code - It is ready to play:

```
class Neural_Net:
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, activation_function, learning_rate, runs):
        self.activation_function = activation_function
        self.X_train = np.linspace(0,1,1000)
        self.y_train = self.X_train**2
        plt.plot(self.X_train, self.y_train)
        self.y_pred = None
        self.W_input = np.random.randn(1, 3)
        self.Partials_W_input = np.random.randn(1, 3)
        self.W_hidden = np.random.randn(3,3)
        self.Partials_W_hidden = np.random.randn(3,3)
        self.W_output = np.random.randn(3,1)
        self.Partials_W_output = np.random.randn(3,1)
        self.Activations = np.ones((3,2))
        self.Partials = np.ones((3,2))
        self.Output_Gradient = None
        self.Loss = 0
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.runs = runs
        self.Losses = []
        self.i = 0

    def apply_activation_function(self, activation_vector):
            return 1/(1+np.exp(-activation_vector))

    def forward_pass(self, training_instance):
        for layer in range(len(self.Activations[0])):
            # For the first layer between X and the first hidden layer
            pre_activation_first = self.W_input.T @ training_instance.reshape(1,1)
                # print('pre activation: ', pre_activation)
                # Apply the activation function
                self.Activations[:,0] = self.apply_activation_function(pre_activation_first).ravel()
            else:
                pre_activation_hidden = self.W_hidden.T @ self.Activations[:, layer-1]
                self.Activations[:, layer] = self.apply_activation_function(pre_activation_hidden)
                # print('Activations: ', self.Activations)
        output = self.W_output.T @ self.Activations[:, -1]
        # print('output: ', output)
        return output

    def backpropagation(self, y_true, training_instance):
        if self.activation_function == 'linear':
            # Calculate the ouput gradient
            self.Output_Gradient = -(y_true-self.y_pred)
            # print('Output Gradient: ', self.Output_Gradient)

            # Calculate the partial gradients of the Error with respect to the pre acitvation values in the nodes
            self.Partials[:, 1] = self.Activations[:, 1]*(1-self.Activations[:, 1])*(self.W_output @ self.Output_Gradient)
            self.Partials[:, 0] = self.Activations[:, 0]*(1-self.Activations[:, 0])*(self.W_hidden @ self.Partials[:, 1])
            # print('Partials: ', self.Partials)

            # Calculate the Gradients with respect to the weights
            self.Partials_W_output = self.Output_Gradient * self.Activations[:, -1]
            # print('Partials_W_output: ', self.Partials_W_output)
            self.Partials_W_hidden = self.Partials[:, -1].reshape(3,1) * self.Activations[:, 0].reshape(1,3)
            # print('Partials_W_hidden: ',self.Partials_W_hidden)
            self.Partials_W_input = (self.Partials[:, 0].reshape(3,1) * training_instance.T).T
            # print('Partials_W_input: ', self.Partials_W_input)

    def weight_update(self, training_instance, learning_rate):

        # Output Layer weights
        w_output_old = self.W_output.copy()
        self.W_output = w_output_old - learning_rate*self.Output_Gradient

        # Hidden Layer weights
        w_hidden_old = self.W_hidden.copy()
        self.W_hidden = w_hidden_old - learning_rate * self.W_hidden
        # print('W_hidden new: ', self.W_hidden)

        # Input Layer weights
        w_input_old = self.W_input.copy()
        self.W_input = w_input_old - learning_rate * self.W_input
        # print('W_input new: ', self.W_input)


    def train_model(self):
        for _ in range(self.runs):
            for instance in range(len(self.X_train)):
                # forward pass
                self.y_pred = self.forward_pass(self.X_train[instance])

                # Calculate loss
                self.Loss = self.calc_loss(self.y_pred, self.y_train[instance])
                # print('Loss: ', self.Loss)

                # Calculate backpropagation
                self.backpropagation(self.y_train[instance], self.X_train[instance])

                # Update weights
                self.weight_update(self.X_train[instance], self.learning_rate)

        # print(self.Losses)
        # plt.plot(range(len(self.Losses)), self.Losses)
        # plt.show()

        # Make predictions on training data to check if the model is basically able to fit the training data
        predictions = []
        for i in np.linspace(0,1,1000):
            predictions.append(self.make_prediction(i))
        plt.plot(np.linspace(0,1,1000), predictions)


    def make_prediction(self, X_new):
        return self.forward_pass(X_new)


    def calc_loss(self, y_pred, y_true):
        loss = (1/2)*(y_true-y_pred)**2
        self.Losses.append(loss[0])
        return (1/2)*(y_true-y_pred)**2

    def accuracy(self):
        pass


Neural_Net('linear', 0.0001, 10).train_model()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue:
First I have mixed up some dimensions which I have corrected. Though, the true issue has been the weight update where I have tried to update the weights with e.g.

```
self.W_hidden = w_hidden_old - learning_rate * self.W_hidden
```

but this is wrong since the learning rate has to be multiplied with the partial of the error with respect to the weights and not with the weights matrix itself. So the correct way is:

```
self.W_hidden = w_hidden_old - learning_rate * self.Partials_W_hidden
```

After that I receive the following result and loss curve:

[image]

[image]
The final code is:

```
class Neural_Net:
    """
    """
    def __init__(self, activation_function, learning_rate, runs):
        self.activation_function = activation_function

        self.Data = pd.read_csv(r"U:\19_035_Machine_Learning_Workshop\2_Workshopinhalt\Weitere\Neural Networks\AirQualityUCI\AirQualityUCI.csv", sep=';', decimal=b',').iloc[:, :-2].dropna()
        self.X_train = np.linspace(0,5,1000)
        self.y_train = np.sin(self.X_train)
        plt.plot(self.X_train, self.y_train)
        self.y_pred = None
        self.W_input = np.random.randn(1, 3)
        self.Partials_W_input = np.random.randn(1, 3)
        self.W_hidden = np.random.randn(3,3)
        self.Partials_W_hidden = np.random.randn(3,3)
        self.W_output = np.random.randn(3,1)
        self.Partials_W_output = np.random.randn(3,1)
        self.Activations = np.zeros((3,2))
        self.Partials = np.zeros((3,2))
        self.Output_Gradient = None
        self.Loss = 0
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.runs = runs
        self.Losses = []
        self.i = 0

    def apply_activation_function(self, activation_vector):
        # print('activation: ', 1/(1+np.exp(-activation_vector)))
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-activation_vector))

    def forward_pass(self, training_instance):
        for layer in range(len(self.Activations[0])):
            # For the first layer between X and the first hidden layer
            if layer == 0:
                pre_activation_first = self.W_input.T @ training_instance.reshape(1,1)
                # print('pre activation: ', pre_activation)
                # Apply the activation function
                self.Activations[:,0] = self.apply_activation_function(pre_activation_first).ravel()
            else:
                pre_activation_hidden = self.W_hidden.T @ self.Activations[:, layer-1]
                self.Activations[:, layer] = self.apply_activation_function(pre_activation_hidden)
                # print('Activations: ', self.Activations)
        output = self.W_output.T @ self.Activations[:, -1].reshape(-1,1)
        # print('output: ', output)
        return output

    def backpropagation(self, y_true, training_instance):
        if self.activation_function == 'sigmoid':
            pass
        if self.activation_function == 'linear':
            # Calculate the ouput gradient
            self.Output_Gradient = -(y_true-self.y_pred)
            # print('Output Gradient: ', self.Output_Gradient)

            # Calculate the partial gradients of the Error with respect to the pre acitvation values in the nodes
            self.Partials[:, 1] = ((self.Activations[:, 1]*(1-self.Activations[:, 1])).reshape(-1,1)*(self.W_output @ self.Output_Gradient)).ravel()
            self.Partials[:, 0] = self.Activations[:, 0]*(1-self.Activations[:, 0])*(self.W_hidden @ self.Partials[:, 1])
            # print('Partials: ', self.Partials)

            # Calculate the Gradients with respect to the weights
            self.Partials_W_output = self.Output_Gradient * self.Activations[:, -1]
            # print('Partials_W_output: ', self.Partials_W_output)
            self.Partials_W_hidden = self.Partials[:, -1].reshape(3,1) * self.Activations[:, 0].reshape(1,3)
            # print('Partials_W_hidden: ',self.Partials_W_hidden)
            self.Partials_W_input = (self.Partials[:, 0].reshape(3,1) * training_instance.T).T
            # print('Partials_W_input: ', self.Partials_W_input)

    def weight_update(self, training_instance, learning_rate):

        # Output Layer weights
        w_output_old = self.W_output.copy()
        self.W_output = w_output_old - learning_rate*self.Partials_W_output.reshape(-1,1)

        # Hidden Layer weights
        w_hidden_old = self.W_hidden.copy()
        self.W_hidden = w_hidden_old - learning_rate * self.Partials_W_hidden
        # print('W_hidden new: ', self.W_hidden)

        # Input Layer weights
        w_input_old = self.W_input.copy()
        self.W_input = w_input_old - learning_rate * self.Partials_W_input
        # print('W_input new: ', self.W_input)


    def train_model(self):
        # print('Initially predicted Value: ', self.make_prediction(self.X_test[0]))
        # print('True value: ', self.y_test[0])
        for _ in range(self.runs):
            for instance in range(len(self.X_train)):
                # forward pass
                self.y_pred = self.forward_pass(self.X_train[instance])

                # Calculate loss
                self.Loss = self.calc_loss(self.y_pred, self.y_train[instance])
                # print('Loss: ', self.Loss)

                # Calculate backpropagation
                self.backpropagation(self.y_train[instance], self.X_train[instance])

                # Update weights
                self.weight_update(self.X_train[instance], self.learning_rate)

        # print(self.Losses)
        # plt.plot(range(len(self.Losses)), self.Losses)
        # plt.show()

        # Make predictions
        predictions = []
        for i in np.linspace(0,5,1000):
            predictions.append(self.make_prediction(i)[0])
        plt.plot(np.linspace(0,5,1000), predictions)


    def make_prediction(self, X_new):
        return self.forward_pass(X_new)

    def calc_loss(self, y_pred, y_true):
        loss = (1/2)*(y_true-y_pred)**2
        self.Losses.append(loss[0])
        return (1/2)*(y_true-y_pred)**2

    def accuracy(self):
        pass

Neural_Net('linear', 0.1, 1500).train_model()
```

To optimize the code we have to add bias in the input an hidden layer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your activation function is linear, the entire ANN will provide a simple weighted sum, so a linear output. Practically you are doing linear regression at the moment. It is good for verifying that learning works to some extent (try to teach a number of linear functions), but that is all, for the real thing you need nonlinear.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function#Comparison_of_activation_functions on Wikipedia for ideas. In fact the comparison of functions starts with a recap of desirable features, and the first one is being nonlinear:

> **Comparison of activation functions**
>
> Some desirable properties in an activation function include:
>
> - Nonlinear – When the activation function is non-linear, then a two-layer neural network can be proven to be a universal function approximator.[6] The identity activation function does not satisfy this property. When multiple layers use the identity activation function, the entire network is equivalent to a single-layer model.

Comment: Forgot the nonlinearity in the hidden layer. Added the nonlinearity in the code above. The result is still the same unfortunately